# ListView - как правильно создать шаблон для одного элемента списка?

Tags: android

Какой Layout необходимо использовать для создания одного элемента ListView? при попытке вставить что-то кроме TextView в этот шаблон в самом приложении происходят вылеты, оно останавливается.

Comment: любой можно использовать. если у вас "вылетает", приведите стектрейс при вылете и соответствующий код. в текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно ответить ничего вразумительного и полезного

Comment: ок, а нужно ли какой-то id давать TextView, который будет отображать вводимый текст элемента?

Comment: если вы к нему собираетесь обращаться из кода, то да.

Comment: и какой же? для ListView он обязательно должен быть android:list, а тут?

Comment: любой, для списка тоже не обязательно какой вы указали. Данный ресурс не предполагает обсуждение в комментариях. Оформите свой вопрос так, чтобы он максимально раскрывал вашу действительную проблему, привидите код и сообщения о ошибке, чтобы на него можно было дать полноценный ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил проблему.
Изначально у меня в xml-шаблоне для отдельного пункта списка был лишь один TextView, соответственно и все, что надо было указать в адаптере - это этот самый шаблон.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.new_task_element, data);
```

Но так как я собирался создать layout и внутри него - TextView, было необходимо указать id как layout'а, так и TextView внутри него, чтобы студия распознала этот самый TextView.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.new_task_element, R.id.text_element, data);
```

Теперь в этот самый шаблон для отдельного пункта списка можно вставлять все, что угодно. Мой пост - это единственная инфа на русском языке по этой проблеме